# PyQt QFileDialog does not close when using native dialog

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using PyQt to get a filename form the user.  I have developed a minimum example to show the issue.  If I use the static function QFileDialog.getOpenFileName, and I pass the QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, the file dialog behaves as expected.  If I do not provide that option, the dialog will not close when the user selects a file.  The dialog only closes after the script completes execution.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
a = QApplication(sys.argv) 
filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', '.', '*',    '*', QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog) #works
#filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', '.', '*', '*') #doesn't work
a.quit()
a = None
print filename
print "Dialog should be gone"
time.sleep(10)
```

When the user selects a file, if "DontUseNativeDialog" is not used, the dialog will stay up until after the 10 second sleep.  I'd expect the dialog to close as soon as the user clicks OK or Cancel.

Comment: what do you mean 'native' - Windows, Linux or MacOS ?

Comment: most GUI needs `mainloop` (`event loop`) to work. You can use `a.exec_()` (before `a=None`) to start mainloop in PyQt and it closes dialog but then you will have problem to stop this mainloop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most `GUI` needs `mainloop` (`event loop`) which runs all time and makes all job in GUI.

You can use `a.exec_()` to start `mainloop` in `PyQt` and it closes dialog but then you will have problem how to stop this mainloop :)

`a.quit()` can close it but if you use it before `a.exec_()` then `mainloop` doesn't receive this message and doesn't close. If you put after `a.exec_()` then it will be never executed because `a.exec_()` blocks all code till you ends `mainloop`. But you can use `QTimer` with `a.quit` to inform `mainloop` to execute it after it will be started.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

a = QApplication(sys.argv) 

#filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', '.', '*',    '*', QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog) #works
filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', '.', '*', '*') #doesn't work

# run a.quit after 100ms
QTimer.singleShot(100, a.quit)
# run mainloop
a.exec_()

print(filename)
print "Dialog should be gone"
time.sleep(10)
```